# MSAccess VBA ORDER BY not working on dynamic recordsource

Tags: ms-access, vba

The below code sets the recordsource on my form. The ORDER BY is not working since all the form properties are blank. How do I get sort?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    If Me.OpenArgs <> "" Then

        Me.AllowFilters = True
        Me.FilterOn = True
        Me.RecordSource = "QRY: BPRIL Data Entry By Order"
        Me.Filter = Me.OpenArgs
        Me.Requery

    ElseIf (Me.RecordSource <> "BPRIL Data Entry") Then

        Me.RecordSource = "BPRIL Data Entry"
        Me.Requery

    End If

    Me.OrderBy = "[Item #]"
    Me.OrderByOn = True
```

End Sub

Comment: The correct one is Item # with a space.

Comment: When you say that Order By is not working because all the form properties are blank, what do you mean? Have you tried `?Screen.ActiveForm.OrderBy` in the immediate window? I ask, because the above should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the recordsource, why not take the opportunity to sort?

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT Stuff FROM [BPRIL Data Entry] ORDER BY [Item #]"
```

You should consider doing yourself a favour and getting rid of spaces in table names and field names, it will make life a lot easier.

Comment: I try to avoid placing SQL in my VBA code. Plus the SQL for the "QRY: BPRIL Data Entry By Order" is a bit long and complex.